# Override Date constructor

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to override the Date constructor to check for a valid date before creating a new Date object? For example i have some situations where dates are dynamically created and wrong dates are created. So if i create `let d = new Date(2019, 1, 31)` i want the date constructor to check that the day is within bounds of how many days are in the month to be created.

So currently if i run `let d = new Date(2019, 1, 31)` it will create a date of March 3 2019 because there are only 28 days in February. I want the date constructor to verify that first and if the day is out of bounds then create the date as `let d = new Date(2019, 1, 28)` which is February 28 2019.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can override everything in JS:

```
 const OriginalDate = Date;
 Date = function(...args) {
   // fancy checks
   return new OriginalDate(...args);
 };
```

But be aware: Changing JS internals might break code *somewhere* on the page, so you should never do that in larger production projects.

Comment: Yea its for a large production application so i dont want to possibly break anything else, i guess the safest bet is to just create a wrapper around the date object and create it that way?

Comment: @user616 jup, that could only break the code using it. You could also only define `Date` in a local scope, then it will only be accessible there.